# How to cleanup Code Analysis rule set history?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

I want to set common rule set for solution.

To do this, I have to open each project properties, select "Code Analysis" tab, and browse for rule set, since "Analyze -> Configure Code Analysis -> For Solution" menu hasn't an option to browse for file.

While playing with Code Analysis, I've created number of test rule sets. Now, when I want to select rule set, Visual Studio displays all history:

[image]

How to cleanup it? I can't find a place, where history is stored.

Answer (score 2):

I've found one unobvious way to do this.

To remove rule set from history:

- remove file from disk
- select "Choose multiple rue sets..." item from drop down list
- select removed rule set in list
- Visual Studio will ask about removing it; confirm
- restart Visual Studio.

[image]

Is this the only way?